# Loop thorough Json Object - JS

Tags: javascript, json

I am receiving a response in json form like below. How do i loop through to display the user of person1 and person2? I keep getting undefined in my console. What am i not doing right?

**data**

```
 {
"person1" :  {
"user": "David"  ,

},
"person2" : {
 "user":  "Crave"  ,
}
}
```

**function**

```
    this.service.fetch(message){

      display1 = message.person1.user;
      display2 = message.person2.user;
}
```

Comment: What's with all the whitespace in your user key?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object

Comment: @AleksandarMisich, white spaces in the user key can use errors?

Comment: you've edited out the spaces. why? were they there, or were they not?

Comment: `this.service.fetch(message){ ... }` --- what's this?

Comment: yes regarding whitespace...`message.person1[" user "]` is not same as `message.person1["user"]`

Comment: @charlietfl. got it.. that worked..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the spacing around the attributes, working with this json object will require `[]` notation. eg. `json[" person1 "]["  user "]`. Removing the spacing will allow us to use `.` notation.
For example:

```
{
  "person1" :  {
    "user": "David",
  },
  "person2" : {
     "user": "Crave",
  }
}
```

Then, to loop through the json object, we can use a for-in to loop through the keys of the object (in this case key = [person1, person2]). If we assume the below users variable equals the json object above:

```
for(key in users) { 
    console.log(users[key].user) // Will console.log "David", then "Crave"!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are spaces in your key names. If you remove the spaces before and after user to make it "user" and before and after " person1 " to make it "person1" it should work.

Answer (score 0):

something along these lines should work just fine. You can easily apply the same sort of logic to your issue.

```
var data =  
{
"person1":{
 "user":"David"},
 "person2":{
 "user":"Crave"
}
};

function show_data(){
 console.log(data.person1.user);
 console.log(data.person2.user);
}

show_data();
```

This simply makes it easy to assign the object to a variable, and access it in the showdata() function.